# Cannot create a file using a PHP script

Tags: php, linux, debian

I have a simple PHP script that creates a file.

```
$path = "/logs/myapp/file.txt";
touch($path);
$logfile = fopen($path, "w") or die('Unable to create the file.');
```

But the script is returning *Unable to create the file* when I'm calling the script from a web browser `mydomain.com/writetofile.php`.

I'm on a Linux Debian Jessie machine and PHP scripts are running as `admin` user (Confirmed by `whoami` in a PHP script and grepping processes (`ps`) list). (I'm using VestaCP if that matters.). `/logs/myapp` directory has `755` permissions for `admin:admin`. Setting the permission to `777` won't work too.

However, if I run the same script using command-line with `admin` user, it works.

EDIT:

PHP script is placed at `/home/admin/web/mydomain.com/public_html`. `is_writable()` to this path returns `true`. However, `is_writable()` to `/logs/myapp` returns 0 even though the owner and group of the directory is `admin` with 755 permission.

EDIT2: My web server is *nginx* with *Apache* as backend.

Comment: Are you une apache?. The user forma apache it's not admin, it's www-data or apache.

Comment: It's nginx server.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/433265/how-do-i-change-the-nginx-user

Comment: Is it an option to create the file before hand and set the permissions by hand so that www-data (assuming that is the group that is writing) - will be able to just update the file?

Comment: Telling you how to fix this is not doing you any favours, the permissions model on this host seem to be very badly configured (and not because it's not letting you write the file).

Comment: @symcbean It's a standard Nginx + apache configuration from VestaCP. https://vestacp.com/install/

Comment: Then go find another provider.

Comment: @symcbean Wow! Didn't see that coming. I can't do that. My app is already live with this configuration.